# How can I create a button to change part of an href?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to have users enter text (input or textarea) and on submit will replace part of a link in an href.

I.e.:
< id="user-form" Textarea> My. Email

So user submits email and changes the email section only of the link in the contract link I'd.

Comment: What does the existing href value look like? (It's also not clear what `I.e.: < id="user-form" Textarea> My. Email` means.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just to have your source url and then feed it with the input

```js
function changeURL(){
var source = "https://www.google.com/"
var input  = document.getElementById("getData").value
document.getElementById("link").href = source + input
console.log(document.getElementById("link").href)
document.getElementById("getData").value = ""
}
```

```html
<input id="getData" placeholder="email"/>
<br/>
<a id="link" href="https://www.google.com"> link </a>
<br/>
<button onclick="changeURL()">Click me </button>
```